# Make a program that outputs a pattern of lines whose width and height is based on the number in the input

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to devise a program to input a positive integer, and by using XX characters – output a figure that has n rows and each row k has k pairs of XX.

For instance, if input is 5, the output will be:

```
XX
XX XX
XX XX XX
XX XX XX XX
XX XX XX XX XX
```

if the input is 3, the output will be:

```
XX
XX XX
XX XX XX
```

What I have tried:

```js
   
function figure() {

 
  var outputObj = document.getElementById("output");
  outputObj.style.fontSize = "11px";
  outputObj.style.textAlign = "left";

   
  var n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number: ", ""));

  for (var x = 1; x <= n; x = x + 1) {
    outputObj.innerHTML += "XX";

    for (var k = 1; k <= n; k = k + 1) {
      outputObj.innerHTML = "<br>";
    }
  }

 
  outputObj.innerHTML = outputObj.innerHTML + "<br><br>" + "program ended";
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "true");
}

figure();
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: _"a program that outputs a figure based on input"_ ...this is, if you take it to its logical conclusion, what every computer program in the world does, at the basic level. It's meaningless as a question title.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't exist to do other people's homework. Have you made an attempt? If so, please include it in your question

Comment: _"I have to do this"_ ...yes, you do. We're not a free write-my-code service, or a tutorial site. We'll _help_ you when you get stuck. Generally, unless it's trivial, we won't just hand you ready-made solutions on a plate. The purpose of this site is to create repository of useful, interesting and widely applicable programming questions for the benefit of future readers. Doing your homework for you doesn't help us achieve that goal. Please ask us something more specific, once you've tried to implement this and got stuck somewhere particular.

Comment: @SinaHeidari _"why don't you look at the question"_ ...I did. And that was my comment on it. Meaningful questions get meaningful answers. Meaningless questions don't. The point of my comment was to prompt you to ask something meaningful and precise...and thereby improve your chances of getting an answer. So, I _was_ helping, if you think about it a little more carefully :-)

Comment: I'm working on this thing for hours and I don't think this is a write my code service. I'm stuck on the second loop that determines the number of characters in one line.

Comment: I see you posted your "attempt", which is literally pasted right off of Chegg. Once again, Stackoverflow is not here to solve your homework questions.

Comment: your code has a runtime error - if you run the snippet I've just created, you'll see it's because `i` is not defined. Does this same error show up in your Console when you run it yourself? or did you miss something out from what you posted? What do you expect the value of `i` to be? please take care to give us an accurate sample.

Comment: I fixed it. It was a mistype

Comment: ok good. Now at least we have something to work with. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson The boilerplate is, looks like the two loops are actually his attempt.

Comment: @BriceFrisco I did not copy code from any website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't a million miles away. The loops just need tweaking so that they depend on each other more.

Specifically, you need to output the correct number of `XX`s per row, not just one each time - making use of `k` to determine that, as per your requirements. And a new line should be made only whenever the number of `XX`s printed is equal to the current line number (i.e. when `k` is the same as `x`).

Demo:

```js
function figure() {
  var outputObj = document.getElementById("output");
  var n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number: ", ""));

  for (var x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
    for (var k = 1; k <= x; k++) {
      outputObj.innerHTML += "XX ";
      if (k == x) outputObj.innerHTML += "<br>";

    }
  }

  outputObj.innerHTML = outputObj.innerHTML + "<br><br>" + "program ended";
}

figure();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. sorry if the question was unclear I'm new to the community.

Comment: It was a lot clearer once you posted the code :-). It was a nice little puzzle to solve in the end. Anyway if the answer has helped please remember to mark it as "accepted" - thanks!